# How to prevent one command from triggering ERR trap?

Tags: bash, trap

I am using an ERR trap to catch any error in my bash script and output what happened to log. (similar to this question: [Trap, ERR, and echoing the error line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39623/trap-err-and-echoing-the-error-line) ) It works as expected. The only problem is, that at some point in my script an exitcode !=0 is expected to happen. How can I make the trap not trigger in this situation?

Here is some code:

```
err_report() {
    echo "errexit on line $(caller)" | tee -a $LOGFILE 1>&2
}

trap err_report ERR
```

Then later in the script:

```
<some command which occasionally will return a non-zero exit code>

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    <handle stuff>
fi
```

Everytime the command returns non-zero my trap is triggered. Can I avoid this only for this part of the code?

I checked this question: [Correct behavior of EXIT and ERR traps when using `set -eu`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/208112/correct-behavior-of-exit-and-err-traps-when-using-set-eu)
but I am not really getting how to apply it to my case - if at all aplicable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An `ERR` `trap` will not trigger if an error code is immediately "caught", which means that you *can* use `if` statements and whatnot without having to flip error trapping on and off all the time.  However, you *cannot* use checking `$?` for flow control, because as the time you get to that check, you already (may) have the uncaught error.

If you have a command you expect to fail -- and you *do not* want those failures to trigger the `trap`, you simply have to catch the failure.  Wrapping them in an `if` statement is clunky and verbose, but this shorthand works nicely:

```
/bin/false || :  # will not trigger an ERR trap
```

However, if you want to do things when a command fails, `if` will be fine here:

```
if ! /bin/false; then
    echo "this was not caught by the trap!"
fi
```

Or alternatively, `else` will catch the error state also:

```
if /bin/false; then
    : # dead code
else
    echo "this was not caught by the trap!"
fi
```

In sum, `set -e` and `trap "command" ERR` only get tripped if there is an error condition which is not immediately and intrinsically accounted for.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The "problem" is that the command above is not a simple command but rather a command chain with pipes which already takes up several lines. Is there a nice way to put this as `if` condition?

Comment: Just as with one command:  `if ! foo | bar | baz | quux; then stuff; fi`.

Comment: I'd buy you lunch, but all I can do is upvote.

Comment: I appreciate the thought of the former, but will happily accept the latter (:

Comment: What's the expected behavior when `set +e` is used? Is the expectation that the script ignores the error and continues to run, but trap ERR is nevertheless triggered?

Comment: `set +e` is the opposite of `set -e`.  `set -e` will cause the script to bail on any uncaught error regardless of if a `trap` is set.  `set +e` will allow a script to continue, though a `trap` set to `ERR` should still fire irrespective to how the `e` switch is toggled.

Answer (score 3):

You can enable/disable the `ERR` trap during portions of you code as necessary.

```
#!/bin/bash
err_report() {
    echo "errexit on line $(caller)"
}
trap err_report ERR
trap - ERR             # disable ERR trap
false
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    printf "OK\n"
else
    printf "FAIL\n"    # prints FAIL
fi
trap err_report ERR    # enable ERR trap
false                  # prints errexit on line 14
```

Answer (score 3):

I find that I often want to avoid ERR trap but I don't want to discard the return code of my function either.  So the pattern I use is this:

```
RC=0
some_function || RC=$?
```

Then I do whatever I need to do with RC.

Comment: Brilliant! This can also be applied to subshells, e.g. `OUTPUT="$(some_function)" || RC="$?"`. Note that the assignment should be done outside the subshell, as its variables cannot be read from outside.

Answer (score 2):

The `ERR` trap obeys the same rules as `set -e`, that is, it doesn't take effect on commands that are used as conditions. So,

```
trap "echo error" ERR
false                     # this should trigger the trap
if ! false; then          # this shouldn't
     echo handle stuff
fi
```

Remember that the command in the `if` condition can be *any* command, it doesn't have to be `[ .. ]`. So, if you only want a true/false evaluation of the exit status of a command, just use it directly in the `if` condition.

If you need to save the exit code *and* avoid the `ERR` trap, you'll need to do something like

```
somecmd && :; ret=$?
```

Here, the `&&` will squash the `ERR` trap, but since it only runs if the exit code is zero, we'll know the exit code is the same after `:`.

You may want to check [BashFAQ 105: Why doesn't set -e (or set -o errexit, or trap ERR) do what I expected?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105)